# Routing loop issue

Tags: networking, route

We have a application having certain ip, let say myapplication.com
The traceroute to the application give result something like below.
The Ip and the time is just for illustration purpose.
If you see 10.10.28.100, it appears 4 times and seems to be a routing loop and adding delay in the application response time.  Is it really a routing loop and is it comman in an enterprise ?

`Tracing route to myapplication.com [10.10.56.100]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
1   244 ms     4 ms     4 ms  vodafonemobile.wifi [192.168.56.1]
2   100 ms     210ms    200 ms  10.10.28.100
3    92 ms     90ms     100 ms  10.10.28.100
4    95 ms     100ms    110 ms  10.10.28.100
5   219 ms     203 ms   202 ms  10.10.28.100
6   219 ms     210 ms   202 ms  10.10.56.100
Trace complete.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall usually blocks incoming traffic, and will replace the hop addresses in traceroutes with destination address. So, that is normal, it is not a routing loop. As you can see, your time is changing for each hop, 4ms, 200ms, 100ms and so on.